# R new column summarizing count of groups of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, dplyr

```
library(data.table)
df <- structure(
  list(
    type = c("AAA", "AAA", "AAA", "BCD", "BCD", "BCD", "EEE", "EEE", "EEE", "EEE"), 
    date = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-05", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-04")
    ), 
  .Names = c("type", "date"), 
  class = "data.frame", 
  row.names = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L))
df$date <- as.Date(df$date)
df
```

sets up the following example data frame uniquely named 'df'

```
  type       date
0  AAA 2015-01-01
1  AAA 2015-01-01
2  AAA 2015-01-01
3  BCD 2015-01-02
4  BCD 2015-01-05
5  BCD 2015-01-05
6  EEE 2015-01-04
7  EEE 2015-01-04
8  EEE 2015-01-04
9  EEE 2015-01-04
```

I am asking for help on how base R, data.table, 
or even dplyr lovers create **a
new column which lists the number of 
times a 'type' is recorded for a given 'date'.**

```
  type       date typeDateGroup
0  AAA 2015-01-01             3 
1  AAA 2015-01-01             3
2  AAA 2015-01-01             3
3  BCD 2015-01-02             1
4  BCD 2015-01-05             2
5  BCD 2015-01-05             2
6  EEE 2015-01-04             4
7  EEE 2015-01-04             4
8  EEE 2015-01-04             4
9  EEE 2015-01-04             4
```

If it helps knowing, in contrast to this example, usually my data includes 3-5mm rows.

don't run this, it was my attempt, and it fails...

```
library(data.table)
df <- as.data.table(df)
df<-df[order(type, date), `:=`(typeDateGroup = .N), by=type, date]
```

Thank you for looking at this and dominating with your skills.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of options:

```
## Using base R only:
df <- transform(df, typeDateGroup=ave(as.numeric(date), type, date, FUN=length))

## With data.table:
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, typeDateGroup:=.N, by=c("type","date")]
```

Answer (score 5):

For future knowledge, in your `data.table` version, if you want to override `df` just do assigment by reference, i.e., `setDT(df)` instead of `df <- as.data.table(df)`.

Also, when using assignment by reference (`:=`) within the `data.table` object, there is no need in `df<-`.

Moreover, you can also sort your `data.table` using `data.table`s `setorder` function (though don't have to, not in this specific case, neither in general).

Lastly, when passing two variables into the `by` argument, you should use either `list(type, date)` or `.(type, date)` or `c("type", "date")` or `"type,date"`

So for completeness, here's the `dplyr` version

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(type, date) %>% 
  mutate(typeDateGroup = n())
```